# Connect to Tablet for Display or as a Display unit?

Tags: connection, connectors

I have an iBall i701 at my spare which I would like to use as the display module. The product link is given below:

[iBall 1701](http://www.amazon.in/iBall-i701-Tablet-Dongle-covers/dp/B00XVGQ0WM)

Could I use the aforementioned product since it has a HDMI outlet? It has pre-installed Windows OS with it.

Answer (score 2):

Tablet / Laptop HDMIs "usually" do not support dual (master and slave) HDMI mode as far as I know. They are usually configured to function in master mode and hence you can connect it to TV or monitor to get tablet / laptop display on TV / monitor but not the other way around. I didn't see anywhere in specs that it supports dual mode, and hence it is most likely that tablet in the question only supports master mode.

However, You can make use of vnc client to get entire display of RPi over your tablet. (I'm not sure if there is any such utility for windows tablets but android play store does have a vnc client). In this case, both of them should be on the same network and [vnc server must be installed on RPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay that was a bummer but it helped a lot to know. I was unable to find a cheap device. Mostly the LCD's costs more than the RPi itself. What would you recommend for a screen that fits hassle-free without much wires hanging around. Again, I wanted to be as neat as possible.

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick I'm afraid that there is no cheap solution if you need a dedicated display since you will need an HDMI driver + LCD. The cheapest I know is priced somewhere around 40 - 50 USD. Link : http://www.ebay.com/itm/7-inch-LCD-Screen-Display-Monitor-for-Raspberry-Pi-Driver-Board-HDMI-VGA-2AV-/331036375689

Comment: I hope [this](http://www.ebay.in/itm/7-inch-Raspberry-Pi-LCD-HDMI-Screen-Display-Module-800-480-/151744452071?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item2354ac95e7) one works out

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick Should work. Yes.